# Converting a .txt file into a JSON in Adobe Acrobat and how to reference it

Tags: javascript, json, adobe, eval

I have a file attached to my PDF entitled JSONTEST.txt.  I have successfully returned a string from that .txt, however, I am now trying to turn that string into a JSON so I can reference it as so (obj[key] returns key value).  In reading, it seems like eval() is what I should be using, however, every time I do, it gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
5:Document-Level:jsontest
```

This is the script I am using:

```
console.show(); console.clear();
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("JSONTEST.txt");
var cFile = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var obj = eval(cFile);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Once it is working, can I reference it as I have described above?

Comment: If JSONTEST.txt should contain json, use JSON.decode, not eval.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, though I'm still trying to figure out the correct way to reference fields.  My JSON text was within curly brackets ( {} ), but should've been within square brackets ( [] ).  Simple as that, so I change it to:

```
var obj = eval('[' + cFile + ']');
```

It seems to work now.